# Why app run in Windows 10, the pivot.item's header shift up and causes the text cut off?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile, pivotitem

My Windows Phone 8.1 app runs well in 8.1. However, recently I tried to move my code to Windows 10, I found that all the pivot.item's header seems shift up and the text has been cut off. Any idea? I'm wondering if there is any way to set header to the center to avoid this problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the end I tried to add some padding to it to solve this problem

```
           <PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Padding="0,10,0,0"  Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.WP_Inbox_PivotItemImportant, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem.Header>
```